# What is the C++ type resulting from addition

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, type-conversion

I'm getting the "ambiguous call" compilation error for this:

```
short i;
MyFunc(i+1, i+1);
```

Where there are two definitions for MyFunc - one taking two shorts, the other taking two floats.

When I write:

```
MyFunc(i, i+1);
```

There's no error - the compiler deduces short.

My question is, how come 'short' + 1 may result as a floating point, and how can I avoid going over all my code and adding explicit casts such as:

```
MyFunc((short)(i+1), (short)(i+1));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i+1` is promoted to `int` as `short` is a smaller integral type than `int`.

so `MyFunc(i+1, i+1);` is "`MyFunc(int, int);`"

You might resolve the ambiguity by adding overload which does the dispatch expected, something like:

```
void MyFunc(short, short);
void MyFunc(float, float);

template <typename T1, typename T2>
std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T1>::value || 
               std::is_floating_point<T2>::value>
MyFunc(T1 t1, T2 t2)
{
    MyFunc(static_cast<float>(t1), static_cast<float>(t2));
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
std::enable_if<!std::is_floating_point<T1>::value &&
               !std::is_floating_point<T2>::value>
MyFunc(T1 t1, T2 t2)
{
    MyFunc(static_cast<short>(t1), static_cast<short>(t2));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370732/what-does-natural-size-really-mean-in-c) when using `short` in arithmetic operations, it must be first converted into an `int`.So actually the compiler is trying to find the correct `MyFunc(int,int)` and has to choose between `MyFunc(short,short)` and `MyFunc(float,float)`, hence the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

During addition, if operands are smaller than `int`, they are promoted to `int` and the result of `i + 1` is also an `int`. For more check this [link](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules). At this point during [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) an integral to float type conversion occurs.